# This war belongs to Men or the Men?

Tags: grammar

If I were not a human and wanted to say this war is only for humans, then which of the following should I say?

> 1. This war belongs to Men
> 2. This war belongs to the Men
> 3. This war belongs to man

Comment: *Belongs* sounds funny here.

Comment: Using _man_ to mean the human race used to be standard but is now considered sexist. What's wrong with 'This war is only for humans'?